# Memory discrepancy between Kubernetes Dashboard and actual usage

Tags: docker, kubernetes

So, I was comparing some memory metrics in some pods, and it seems that the reported memory usage seen in Kubernetes Dashboard is different from the output of a `top` command (RES column) from inside the pod/container.

Here it is an example Dashboard screenshot (774 Mib):

[image]

and the output of `top` command inside container:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                   

1 elastic+    20   0    3770364 1.120g 828 S  0.0  15.3     962:37.36 java
```

For completion, the output of `free -h` in that container:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7.3G       6.7G       591M       151M       107M       660M
-/+ buffers/cache:       6.0G       1.3G
Swap:           0B         0B         0B
```

Another example:

[image]

with `top` output:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S     %CPU %MEM   TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                   
  1 elastic+  20  0     3859032 517640 25120 S   1.0   6.7   3:22.52 java
```

In this case the used memory is much less than the reported one.

The Kubernetes version is 1.4.

Comment: Those figures look a bit wrong in any case, but just a note that resident memory != used memory. Actual used memory is better represented by [PSS](https://lwn.net/Articles/230975/) on a linux host availalble in [`/proc/<pid>/smaps`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps)

Comment: Also `free` returns values for the host, not the individual container.